# How to play CS:GO with dual monitor expanded over both monitors?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, graphics-card

I want to play CS:GO using two monitors, each connected via HDMI to a GT 1030. How can I play CS:GO expanded over both monitors?

Comment: Are you trying to expand the game over both monitors?

Comment: yes,i want to  expand the game over both monitors

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. An even number of monitors will make the game pretty much unplayable, though.

Comment: Back in the day I used to use http://www.softth.net/ which worked with any directx game. If you search for "softth counterstrike" you'll find some tutorials. (not posting an answer because I haven't tested any of this)

Comment: As @dly have said, your sight will be in the middle of two monitors... Why would you want to do this?